# cakephp email plugin to pull email by imap

Tags: email, cakephp, imap

I am using [this](https://github.com/nicolasramy/cakephp-emails-plugin) cakephp email plugin to pull the emails from the account. Here are my parameters

```
'datasource' => 'Emails.Imap',
'server' => 'mail.example.com',
'connect' => 'imap/novalidate-cert',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'port' => '143',
'ssl' => false,
'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
'error_handler' => 'php',
```

and I make a query as it is indicated in documentation

```
$ticketEmails = $this->TicketEmail->find('first', array('recursive' => -1));
```

but when I debug the result, the following fields show data like this

```
Array
(
    [TicketEmail] => Array
        (


. . . other fields

            [body] => CjxIVE1MPjxCT0RZPnNvbWUgbWVzc2FnZTxicj48L0JPRFk+PC9IVE1MPgo=

            [plainmsg] => IHNvbWUgbWVzc2FnZQo=

 . . . other fields
        )

)
```

I can not understand why it shows these strings, e.g. in email account's message's body is just this text `some message`.

My cake version is 1.3

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding, looks like the plugin doesn't handle that, it only [checks for the `quoted-printable` format](https://github.com/nicolasramy/cakephp-emails-plugin/blob/master/models/datasources/imap_source.php#L892).

You could [decode the data](http://php.net/base64_decode) in your model, for example in the [Model::afterFind()](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#afterfind) callback or in a custom method, or you could try modifying the plugin so that it returns the decoded data (untested):

```
protected function _fetchPart ($Part) {
    $data = imap_fetchbody($this->Stream, $Part->uid, $Part->path, FT_UID | FT_PEEK);
    if ($data) {
        // remove the attachment check to decode them too
        if ($Part->format === 'base64' && $Part->is_attachment === false) {
            return base64_decode($data);
        }
        if ($Part->format === 'quoted-printable') {
            return quoted_printable_decode($data);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much !! It works now. I have made a couple additions to your answer, after I got that plugin work fine. hope it will be helpful for the other users. Thanks again !!